# Python parsing HTML Using Regular Expressions

Tags: python, html, regex, python-2.7, html-parsing

I am trying to go through the HTML of a website and parse it looking for the max enrollment of a class. I tried checking for a substring in each line of the HTML file, but that would try to parse the wrong lines. So I am now using Regular Expressions. I have `\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="odd">([0-9])|([0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9])<\/td>\r\n` as my regular expression right now, but this regular expression matches the max enrollment as well as the section number. Is there another way to go about what I am trying to extract from the webpage? The HTML code snippet is below:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tableHeader">Section</td>
    <td class="odd">001</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="tableHeader">Credits</td>
    <td class="even" align="left">  4.00</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="tableHeader">Title</td>
<td class="odd">Linear Algebra</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="tableHeader">Campus</td>
    <td class="even" align="left">University City</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="tableHeader">Instructor(s)</td>
    <td class="odd">Guang  Yang</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tableHeader">Instruction Type</td>
    <td class="even">Lecture</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="tableHeader">Max Enroll</td>
    <td class="odd">30</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761

Comment: Have you tried [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)/[`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) instead?

Comment: please help me help you, by improving my answer: what do you mean by the "looking for the max enrollment"? Can you give me example of what you try to get from your html example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: do not agree about the dupe, it's not asking whether it can be done with a regex, it's wrongly trying to do that.

Comment: @zmo which is exactly what the OP of the dupe is trying to do.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. That OP is trying to actually match the tag name, class name, etc. I am just trying to extract the contents in such a way where I don't get the section number AND max enroll number. I just need help with getting only the Max Enroll number.

Comment: Well then instead of sitting there insulting the way I approached this problem, maybe it would be more productive to point me in the right direction, wouldn't it?

Comment: @LukasGraf This really isn't a duplicate anymore, as it's a specific question with correct, *specific* answers.

Comment: @admdrew so what's the specific question? Can you point me to the question mark in the OP's post please?

Comment: What I don't get is that you're saying as a comment *I am just trying to extract the contents in such a way where I don't get the section number AND max enroll number. I just need help with getting only the Max Enroll number.*, but you're accepting the one answer that gives you the section number AND the max enroll number. I don't get your logic.

Comment: @zmo I accepted that answer before you added a few more things to yours, I went through all the answers again.

Comment: @LukasGraf `Is there another way to go about what I am trying to extract (the max enrollment of a class) from the webpage?`

Comment: A decent answer, instead of spoon-feeding a correct solution to the OP, would include an explanation **why** HTML can't be parsed with regular expressions.

Comment: @LukasGraf then it would be most helpful if you could explain why you can't instead of being demeaning in the comment section

Comment: which why I'm giving a link in my all-caps disclaimer. [I could also write it using <blink></blink> using toilet](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&v=1&f=Big&t=DO%20NOT%20PARSE%20HTML)?

Comment: @heinst I already did, and the answer I linked does too: Because HTML isn't [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DO NOT PARSE HTML USING REGEXP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Use the right tool for the right job.

Let's make an analogy to explain why it's wrong: it's like trying to have a [5 year old](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_automaton) understand [Hamlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language), whereas he does not have the [vocabulary and grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) to understand [Shakespeare's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), that he will get when he'll be able to [process more abstract concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton).

Use either [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) or [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to do that.

As an example: to get a list of all the evens and all the odds:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.HTML(your_html_text)
>>> odds = tree.xpath('//td[@class="odd"]/text()')
>>> evens = tree.xpath('//td[@class="even"]/text()')
>>> odds
['001', 'Linear Algebra', 'Guang  Yang', '30']
>>> evens
['  4.00', 'University City', 'Lecture']
```

edit:

> *I am just trying to extract the contents in such a way where I don't get the section number AND max enroll number. I just need help with getting only the Max Enroll number.*

ok, now I'm getting what you want, so here's the solution using lxml:

```
>>> for elt in tree.xpath('//tr'):
...     if elt.xpath('td[@class="tableHeader"]')[0].text == "Max Enroll":
...         elt.xpath('td[@class="odd"]|td[@class="even"]')[0].text
... 
'30'
```

There you have **only** the max enroll number.

Using BeautifulSoup it's a bit easier:

```
>>> bs = BeautifulSoup(your_html_text)
>>> for t in bs.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'tableHeader'}):
...   if t.text == "Max Enroll":
...     print t.findNext('td').text
'30'
```

Comment: `soup.find('td', text="Max Enroll").find_next_sibling('td').text` would be easier.

Comment: indeed, though I'm giving the more general approach here, so the OP can adapt to his dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Use the tool that is specialized on parsing html, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

> Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and
>   XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic
>   ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree. It
>   commonly saves programmers hours or days of work.

For example, here's how you can get what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """your html here"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find('td', text="Max Enroll").find_next_sibling('td').text
```

Prints:

```
30
```

Comment: If I choose this method, I will not be able to give this script to friends very easily for them to use because it will use a library that they (most likely) will not have installed on their computer initially, correct?

Comment: @heinst well, `BeautifulSoup` is a third-party library that can be easily installed. Just include [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/1.1/requirements.html) file with script dependencies and give it to your friends.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate to [zmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23548604/1454048), using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<snipped html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for tableHeaders in soup.find_all('td', class_="tableHeader"):
    if tableHeaders.get_text() == "Max Enroll":
        print tableHeaders.find_next_siblings('td', class_="odd")[0].get_text()
```

Output:

```
30
```